# Hook error using Truffle React box (transforming the App.js from Class component to Functional component)

Tags: truffle, dapps, dapp-development, react, truffle-develop

not an expert Solidity/React user here. I got Truffle React box and I am making a website. My example is very easy. I have this `Nav` element:

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './NavbarElements';

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
       <Nav>
  
       </Nav> 
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Which is defined here:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

    export const Nav = styled.nav`
        background: #000;
    `;
```

Simple. Now, due to some hook errors in React, I decided to convert my `App.js` file. When you download this box, the *App* is a Class component. It means you cannot use hook inside it (as far as I know). So my next step was transform that Class component into a Functional component (some users from the React community helped me in this task). The result was:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null });

  useEffect(() => {    
    async function init() {
      try {
        const web3 = await getWeb3();
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        
        const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
        const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
          SimpleStorageContract.abi,
          deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address
        );
        
        instance.options.address = "0xA65990EC0CA555d2eCDD1d84E9D1397CFA967E60"
        
        setState(value => ({ ...value, web3, accounts, contract: instance }));
      } catch (error) {
        alert("Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.");
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    init();
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function runExample (accounts, contract) {

      await contract.methods.set(25).send({ from: accounts[0] });
      const response = await contract.methods.get().call();
    
      setState(value => ({ ...value, storageValue: response }));
    };
    if(state.accounts != null && state.contract != null) {
      runExample(state.accounts, state.contract);
    }
  }, [state.accounts, state.contract]);
  
    if (!state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The code was reviewed and seems to be fine. I cannot find any errors in it either. But it is again throwing a hook error, but some users think this could be a red herring because as far as I know I am not using any hook. If I remove `<Navbar />` tag at the end of the `App.js` file, the app works perfectly.

Additionally, I checked my version:

- `npm view react version`: 17.0.2
- `npm view react-native version`: 0.65.1

But, in my json file it seems I have another version:

```
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "1.2.2"
```

I can provide a sandbox with my project if it's necessary. Please, this is driving me crazy.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my question with my version of React.

Comment: Do you have a github repository to try? The first thing I'd try is to make it work without web3 and that stuff. Another alternative is to use a premade library like web3-react.

Comment: @Ismael thanks! I really need help on this. Yes, this is my repo: https://github.com/Joncarre/React-DApp I think is not about breaking rules of Hooks, so it could be about my React version... How could I try it without web3?

Comment: I've tried the repo with node v14.15 and it worked without issues after fixing some dependency errors triggered by `yarn build`. In any case I'd suggest to upgrade web3 version, latest is 1.5.

Comment: @Ismael really?! Seriously, you are my hero. You cannot imagine my headache dealing with this. I will try this solution tomorrow and will tell you. Finger crossed!

Comment: @Ismael I have node v14.17. Could it be a problem?

Comment: It should work. I didn't do much, `yarn` to install dependencies, then add missing dependencies resulting from `yarn build`. Once launched metamask ask for confirmation, the transaction fails because I'm on ganache. No react hooks error.

Comment: @Ismael after some issues with React version, it works using node v14.17 and Web3 v1.6. Tysm for you help!